# How to match regex with same format but different in terms of character set?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Suppose i have a string and i want to match only the part where value is empty and not the part where value is present?
for ex : &lang=&val=1233 
I need only &lang and not &val as it has an actual value?
I have this

`&(.+)=(?!\s\S)`
 regex which matches &lang=&val= in the string.
Can anyone help me out

Comment: Will the values always be numeric like that?

Comment: @arshajii it can be anything

Comment: And can there be spaces after or before `=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following regular expression:

```
(?:(?<=\?)|&)[^=]+=(?=&|$)
```

could be explained as:

- `(?: ....)`: non-capturing (does not make a group), this may not needed according to your purpose.
- `\?`: escaped `?` to match `?` literally.
- `(?<=\?)`: meaning "preceded by `?`": `?` is not included to the result.
- `(?=&|$)`: meaning "followed by `&`" or ~at end of the input".

Followings are sample test in Python interactive shell:

```
>>> pattern = r'(?:(?<=\?)|&)[^=]+=(?=&|$)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, '&lang=&val=')
['&lang=', '&val=']
>>> re.findall(pattern, '&lang=&val=1233')
['&lang=']
>>> re.findall(pattern, '&lang=&val=&val2=123&val3=')
['&lang=', '&val=', '&val3=']
>>> re.findall(pattern, '?lang=&val=&val2=123&val3=')
['lang=', '&val=', '&val3=']
>>> re.findall(pattern, '?lang=blah&val=&val2=123&val3=')
['&val=', '&val3=']
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'www.html.com?user=&lang=eng&code=.in')
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted but in some cases i dont have the '&' at the start of url how to match it?

Comment: @NaN, Do you want match `?this=`?  Giving specific example(s) will make it easier to answer.

Comment: @NaN, I updated the regular expression and the code. If that is not what you want, comment (or update the question) with specific example and desired output.

Comment: this works fine but it also matches this : www.html.com?user=&lang=eng&code=.in this case it matches the question mark also. how to deal with that?

Comment: @NaN, Do you want `['user=']` for `www.html.com?user=&lang=eng&code=.in`?

Comment: yh but not the question mark if you understand what i want to do

Comment: JS gives an error on this regex as invalid quantifier ? are u missing out on escaping a character or something?

Comment: `/(?:(?<=\?)|&)[^=]+=(?=&|$)/g`

Comment: @NaN, Hmm, code please, not just regular expression part I already know ;).

Comment: `var regexEmptyParam =  /(?:(?<=\?)|&)[^=]+=(?=&|$)/g; var emptyParam = servicePath.match(regexEmptyParam); servicePath = servicePath.replace(emptyParam,''); `

Comment: @NaN, `servicePath = servicePath.replace(/(?:(\?)|&)[^=]+=(?=&|$)/g, '$1')` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```
(&|?)([^&=]+)=(&|$)
```

(you can use non capturing groups if you need)

but I would just build a hash of all query string parameters and pick the keys without values. it is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[?&]([^&]+)=(&|$)
```

The first group will have the name of your parameter.

Note that this regex will also catch an empty first parameter (`val1` in `foo.php?val1=&val2=ok`)

Comment: it should not match '&' if it has value associated with it

Comment: I don't understand. It does not.

Comment: Changed * for +. Maybe that was what you where talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(&([^=]+))=(?=&)
```